# Why store data with a relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `BlogImage` model and a `Blog` model. Now I want to know if it's correct to use the `create` method with the relation and why it is used this way like below:

```php
$blogImage = new BlogImage();
$blogImage->blog()->create([
    //this is making the blog for me
    'title' => $request->title,
    'content' => $detail,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'author' => Auth::user()->id,
    'meta_description' => $request->title,
    'meta_image' => $meta_image,
]);
```

Also, I want to know what is the difference between this method and the normal form, which is:

```php
Blog::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'content' => $detail,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'author' => Auth::user()->id,
    'meta_description' => $request->title,
    'meta_image' => $meta_image,
]);
```

Comment: You might store data *about* the relationship. For example, if you had an online store, and you added a product to an invoice, you might want to store information about a discount that was applied in the invoice_products relationship table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: in the first example you're creating the `Blog` instance and linking it to `blogImage`, but in the second example you're only creating an instance of the `Blog` model.

In the second example you would have to attach the new `Blog` instance to `blogImage` after creating it with `$blogImage->blog()->attach($blog->id)`.

The first example's `create` method is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) and the second example's is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) in Laravel's documentation.

Either method is correct. It's just shorter to use the first example.